# Remove nodes of a linked list on condition (C)

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I am doing an exercise with a linked list, in which I need to remove some nodes according to a condition. The condition is ''remove the nodes that have a data stored that is less or equal to 'avg''.

I should consider three cases:
- removing the head node
- removing a node in the middle
- removing last node

I used three pointers, but this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Am I accidentally missing some pointers? Thank you in advance!

```
void checkAvg(int avg, struct list* head_node){

   struct list* prev;
   struct list* curr;
   struct list* next;

   prev = head;
   curr = prev->link;
   next = curr->link;

   while (curr!=NULL) {
      if (prev->data <= avg) {
          head = curr;
      }

      if (curr->data <= avg) {
          prev->link = curr->link;
      }

      if (next->data <= avg) {
          curr->link = next->link;
      } 

      prev = prev->link;
      curr = curr->link;
      next = next->link;

   }

}
```

EDIT: 
I am sorry, as you told me, I wasn't specific. The program has to do this:
1) Read a linked list
2) Generate an output average of the values I read (sum of values / # of values)
3) remove from the list the nodes that have a data that is <= to the average
Free the memory of those nodes. 
About the free() part, I have some difficulties with that, so I thought I first had to learn how to properly use pointers. As you may have noticed, I am not really good at that, I am starter.

Thank you for everyone who has replied, I am checking the replies right now

Comment: What happens to your code when `head_node = NULL` ?

Comment: (a) What does `head_node` hold when your list is *empty* ? (b) What happens when the initial node pointed to by `head_node` is the one you want to remove? (c) Is it *intentional* that no actual memory is freed and the nodes you're trying to remove are simply leaked into the ether? In short, you've not provided enough information concerning the code you've chosen *not* to show to allow us to accurately know how your list is managed so any answer you get short of blatant errors will be at-best wags.

Comment: What "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: I am trying to reply to everyone:
haccks The while loop should give a segfault, so that needs a fix I guess
@WhozCraig A) Yes, I just noticed I need a condition for that B) I thought I took care of that with the first if condition, but I guess it doesn't work either C) No that's not intentional, I wanted to take care of it later, because DanFego, what doesn't work is that actually it seems to remove nodes that shouldn't be removed. I am editing the post with more informations right now

Comment: @WhozCraig just published the corrections in my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your linked list does **not** have some sentinel head-node (and I strongly advise that it does not, as `NULL` is a damn fine value to indicate "I'm empty"), removal traversal is not overtly complicated. The places in your code where you seem to go astray are:

- Passing the head pointer by-address and declaring the parameter as a pointer-to-pointer **OR** returning the new head pointer if the old one was disposed.
- Maintaining consistency in your local pointer variables. You have to know *for sure* what everything points to *at all times*.

You can use pointer *values*, or you can use the actual pointers themselves (by address). I prefer the latter. In *either* case, the head node pointer must be passed by-address to allow potential modification of the caller's variable (like everything else in C) or the function can return the potentially new head node address. I prefer the former of those methods, as it leaves you the option of using the function return value for communicating error states to your caller. You're not doing that right now, but you should (hint).

```
void checkAvg(int avg, struct list** pp)
{
    while (*pp)
    {
        if ((*pp)->data <= avg)
        {
            struct list *victim = *pp;
            *pp = victim->link;
            free(victim);
        }
        else
        {   // advance to address of next "link" pointer
            pp = &(*pp)->link;
        }
    }
}
```

It is worth noting this can be significantly simpler if the list is maintained as **sorted** in ascending order. If that is the case, the entire `checkAvg` function becomes substantially simpler. You can exit the loop as soon as you detect a value that no longer fits your condition:

```
void checkAvg(int avg, struct list** pp)
{
    while (*pp && (*pp)->data <= avg)
    {
        struct list *victim = *pp;
        *pp = victim->link;
        free(victim)
    }
}
```

In either case, the function is invoked by passing the head pointer on the caller-side *by-address*:

```
struct list *head = NULL;

//... populate list....

checkAvg(value, &head);
```

---

**How it Works**

A linked list is just something that looks like this:

```
          --------      --------      --------
head ---> | link | ---> | link | ---> | link | ---> NULL
          | val1 |      | val2 |      | val3 |
          --------      --------      --------
```

Using the methods posted, traversing the list uses a pointer-to-pointer, which does something like this:

```
pp --:
     :        --------      --------      --------
    head ---> | link | ---> | link | ---> | link | ---> NULL
              | val1 |      | val2 |      | val3 |
              --------      --------      --------
```

`pp` points to a *pointer*; **not** a node. Initially `pp` holds the address of the `head` pointer (was passed in by-address as a parameter).

So what happens if the first node matches your criteria? Ultimately, this is the result

```
pp --:
     :        --------      --------
    head ---> | link | ---> | link | ---> NULL
              | val2 |      | val3 |
              --------      --------

             --------
 victim ---> | link |
             | val1 |
             --------
```

and the victim node is summarily discarded (the link of victim actually still references the second node, but is meaningless in this context after the detachment happens.

So, what about if the *second* node was the one that needed removal (i.e. we skipped the first node). That gets a little more complicated:

```
         pp -----:
                 :
              ---:----      --------
    head ---> | link | ---> | link | ---> NULL
              | val1 |      | val3 |
              --------      --------
             --------
 victim ---> | link |
             | val2 |
             --------
```

What this is *trying* to show (admittedly poorly) is that the `pp` pointer-to-pointer always holds the address of the pointer that we *may* be modifying. If we don't need to modify that pointer, we change the address held in `pp` to point to the next `link` pointer in the list (obtained through `pp = &(*pp)->link`

The latter case doesn't happen when the list is already sorted , thus the reason its iterative loop is simpler. We just enumerate the list, throwing out nodes until we find one that no longer meets our condition.

But no matter what, `pp` *always holds the address of the pointer that points to the node we're working with.*. Initially, that address is the address of the caller's `head` pointer.

Ok. I can only *hope* that makes it clearer. Some debugging with `printf("pp=%p, *pp=%p\n", pp, *pp)` in the loop makes what is actually happening most-educational. Walking through the algorithms by-hand in a debugger would be *highly* informative.

Comment: Thank you @WhozCraig, this not only works, but explains me everything in detail. Just to be clear I understand the english and the code, what you are doing is: 1) Search for the node that satisfies the condition 2) Copy the node into a 'victim' one 3) now pp is linked to what victim->link was pointing to. What I don't understand, if victim is pp, shouldn't they point at the same node?

Comment: @Roberto close. I'll add an explanation, and if I get time, some ascii-art (though mine is somewhat lame). I'm about to head to a meeting but if I get bored I'll fire up the laptop and write something up. I'll tell you now that no node *copying* is done. the only things moved around here are addresses in pointers.

Comment: -1 does not work: You don't update the link of previous nodes, so if you remove an element in the middle of the list you'll continue to point to it.

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux You're flat wrong. Removing *any* element updates the actually pointer that got you there in the first place (which may be the head node, or may be the prior node's `link` member) directly through `*pp`, where `pp` holds that aforementioned pointers address.

Comment: My bad, you are right. If you edit your answer I'll remove my downvote (which is locked now).

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux no worries. Drawing this in ascii art is a real pain. I may just opt for a picture instead. Egads.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hello, I admit I have a problem with pointer to pointers, as you suggested, I used that printf for debugging, and I noticed that the pp is always the same, even if the it moves forward in the list. 
In the first example, pp points to the pointer head, then it points to a node, shouldn't it point only to pointers?

Comment: @Roberto it always holds the address of a pointer. Never an actual node allocation. However, it is possible for the two to be the same address value. Think about what the address of a node's `link` pointer is (the member's address, *not* its value) if it is the *first* member variable of your struct? According to the standard, the address of a struct is the address of its first member (bitfields not withstanding, its a little odd there). So if your struct is `struct list { struct list *link; .... }` that would explain the addresses you're seeing held in `pp`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier than you think.

You're walking and modifying a linked list, so set up a current and previous.

```
void checkAvg(int avg, struct list** head_node){ //when calling, use checkAvg(avg, &head_node);
    struct list* prev = NULL; 
    struct list* curr = *head_node;
```

Starting at the head...

```
while(curr != NULL){ 
    if(curr->data <= avg){
         if(prev == NULL){
             *head_node = curr->next; //updates the head node
         } else {
             prev->next = curr->next; //removes the unwanted node
         }
    }
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

You really don't need a special end case because the while loop terminates when curr is NULL; for the last item in the list, curr->next is NULL so when it get set it will end the loop. You also don't need to check if the list is empty, because the loop will end if it `curr == NULL` and you assign the head to `curr` at first.

Comment: Hello, I understood what you're telling me, but it doesn't work. Basically it prints an empty list. 
I used checkAvg(avg,&head) but I get a program that ends, but with an empty list. 
P.s. Why do we need a double pointer for the head?

Comment: You need a double pointer because you want to update the head in case you're removing the head. What do you mean by printing an empty list?

Comment: I insert the values in the list:
1) My program prints the list and the average, 
2) I use checkAVG and I ask to the program to print again the list
3) it doesn't print, but just ends the program

Answer (score 1):

I want some recursive magic tonight

```
Node* deleteBad(Node *head, int(*pred)(int)) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (pred(head->value)) {
        head->next = deleteBad(head->next, pred);
        return head;
    }
    else {
        Node *next = head->next;
        free(head);
        return deleteBad(next, pred);
    }
}
```

And accumulators

```
void deleteBad2(Node *head, int(*pred)(int), Node *out) {
    if (head) {
        if (pred(head->value)) {
            out->next = head;
            deleteBad2(head->next, pred, out->next);
        } else {
            out->next = head->next;
            deleteBad2(head->next, pred, out);
        }
    } 
}
```

And for those coxcombs who dislike recursion optimized version

```
void deleteBad3(Node *head, int(*pred)(int), Node *out) {
begin:
    if (head) {
        if (pred(head->value)) {
            out->next = head;
            out = out->next;
            head = head->next;
            goto begin;
        }
        else {
            out->next = head->next;
            head = head->next;
            goto begin;
        }
    }
}
```

and if someone dislike gotos

```
void deleteBad3nogoto(Node *head, int(*pred)(int), Node *out) {
    while (1) {
        if (head) {
            if (pred(head->value)) {
                out->next = head;
                out = out->next;
                head = head->next;

            }
            else {
                out->next = head->next;
                head = head->next;

            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: U dislike recursion, u monster

Comment: Hello, sorry for the dumb question, how does it check if the value is less or equal to the average?

Comment: It uses function pointer. You should define function like
int f(int a) {return a>2;} and send it as a parameter to function
deleteBad(list, f);

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking the data of prev, curr and next, just check for one single data in the loop.
You also need to return the new head in case it changes.
I'd suggest something like that (tested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct list_ {
  struct list_ *link;
  int data;
} list;

list* RemoveElementsBelow(int avg, list* head_node) {
  while (head_node != NULL && head_node->data <= avg) {
    // Remove the first.
    list* new_head = head_node->link;
    free(head_node);
    head_node = new_head;
  }
  if (head_node == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  list* prev;
  list* curr;

  prev = head_node;
  curr = prev->link;

  while (curr != NULL) {
    if (curr->data <= avg) {
      prev->link = curr->link;  // Will be NULL at the end of the list.
      free(curr);
      curr = prev->link;
    } else {
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->link;
    }
  }
  return head_node;
}

list* AddToHead(int value, list* head_node) {
  list* new_node = malloc(sizeof(list));
  new_node->link = head_node;
  new_node->data = value;
  return new_node;
}

list* PrintAndDeleteList(list* head_node) {
  while (head_node != NULL) {
    list* new_head = head_node->link;
    printf("%d ", head_node->data);
    free(head_node);
    head_node = new_head;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  list* my_list = NULL;
  int i;
  int sum = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    int value = atoi(argv[i]);
    sum += value;
    my_list = AddToHead(value, my_list);
  }
  if (argc == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  int avg = sum / (argc - 1);
  printf("Average value: %d\n", avg);

  my_list = RemoveElementsBelow(avg, my_list);

  PrintAndDeleteList(my_list);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled:

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

Tested:
    ./test 10 20 30 40 50
      Average value: 30
      50 40 
    ./test 50 40 30 20 10
      Average value: 30
      40 50

Comment: Hello @Nicolas, just tested this, but it seems that the list remains the same

Comment: Do you call it with head_node = checkAvg(value, head_node) ? Did you try with an element to remove at the beginning, middle, end, and several ones ?

Comment: Yes, as an instance with the list: 10 20 30 40 50
Average is 30
I call checkAvg(average, head) 

It prints 10 20 30 40 50 instead of 40 50

Comment: I just updated my answer to add test code. It looks like it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking each node three times in each iteration, which leads to some weird behavior. Check the head before entering the loop, and only compare the current node each time:

```
void checkAvg(int avg, struct list* head_node){

   struct list* prev;
   struct list* curr;


   while (head!=NULL) {
      if (head->data <= avg) {
          head = head->link;
      } else {
         break;
      }
   }

   prev = head;
   curr = prev->link;

   while (curr!=NULL) {

      if (curr->data <= avg) {
          prev->link = curr->link;

      }
      prev = prev->link;
      curr = prev->link;
   }
}
```